# How to select xml value using xml starlet

Tags: batch, batch-file, xml

How do I retrieve a value using xmlstarlet?

I'm trying to retrieve the Initial value 4.7 from the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GCContextualMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.agilent.com/schemas/Analytical/Instrument/GC7890/2006/">
  <method xmlns="">
    <GC PostRunHoldTime="0" AutoPrepRun="UNKNOWN">
      <Inlet DeterminesReadiness="true">
        ...
      </Inlet>
      <Inlet DeterminesReadiness="true" />
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="true">
        ...
      </Column>
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="true">
        <Setpoints Mode="CONSTANT_FLOW">
          <Flow State="ON" InitialHoldTime="0" InitialValue="4.7" PostRunValue="4.7" />
        </Setpoints>
      </Column>
      <Column DeterminesReadiness="false">
```

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
%cd%\resources\XML.EXE sel -t -c "/GCContextualMethod/method[@xmlns=""]/GC[@PostRunHoldTime="0"]/Column[2]/Setpoints[@Mode="CONSTANT_FLOW"]/Flow[@State="ON"]@InitialValue"  %cd%\GC78901.RapidControl.MethodXML.xml
```

Comment: I'd propose to use powershell to process XML. It's much easier. http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-read-xml-files,2-895.html

Answer (score 0):

In powershell it's just to lines:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path C:\...\test.xml
$XmlDocument.GCContextualMethod.method.GC.Column.Setpoints.Flow.InitialValue | Out-File c:\temp\result.txt
```

Save this to some script.ps1 and change the path to the real xml.
The result 4.7 will be out to the txt file.

Please note that in real xml file all elements like "GCContextualMethod" or "method" must a have a closing one paired to the opening one.
That is not represented in your example.
So, when creating s sample I ended by xml with:

```
 </GC>
</method>
</GCContextualMethod>
```